# При неполной загрузке страницы показывать блок, и при полной загрузке - скрыть

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте. Допустим, у нас есть прелоадер и его CSS-свойства:

```html
<div class="preloader">
  <hr><hr><hr><hr>
</div>
```

```css
body {
  background:white
}

.preloader {
position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
    /* change size for your project */
}
.preloader hr {
  border:0;
  margin:0;
  width:40%;
  height:40%;
  position:absolute;
  animation:spin 3s ease infinite}

.preloader :first-child {
  background:black;
  animation-delay:-1.5s
}
.preloader :nth-child(2) {
  background:grey;
  animation-delay:-1s
}
.preloader :nth-child(3) {
  background:black;
  animation-delay:-0.5s
}

.preloader :last-child {
  background:grey;
}

@keyframes spin{
  0%,100%{transform:translate(0)}
  25%{transform:translate(160%)}
  50%{transform:translate(160%, 160%)}
  75%{transform:translate(0, 160%)}
}
```

```html
<div class="preloader">
  <hr><hr><hr><hr>
</div>
```

И теперь вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы наш прелоадер показывался при неполной загрузке страницы, а когда страница полностью загрузилась, скрыть его? `onload`и `ready` я не знаю, как использовать.

Answer (score 1):

Суть такова, что ты делать прелоадер изначально выше от всех элементов по индексам и позиционируешь фикседом, а когда окно загрузилось скрываешь `preloader` и контент появился "вуаля" :)

Вот рабочий фиддл https://fiddle.jshell.net/5xwmfp48/

```js
$(document).on('load', function() {
   $('#preloader').hide();
});

//or

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#preloader').hide();
});
```

```css
#preloader {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preloader"></div>
```

Comment: Ответ хороший. Но preloader лучше делать вращающимся :)

Answer (score 0):

Вот если надо то пример:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("body").addClass("loaded");
});
```

```css
/* Spinner -START-*/
#loader_wrapper {position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 50;}

#loader {display: block; position: relative; left: 50%; top: 50%; width: 220px; height: 220px; margin: -110px 0px 0px -110px; border: 3px solid transparent; border-top-color: #28C900; border-radius: 50%;

animation: spin 2s linear infinite; 
-webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; 
-o-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; 
-ms-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; -moz-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; z-index: 52;}

#loader::before{content: ""; position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px; bottom: 10px; right: 10px; border: 3px solid transparent; border-top-color: #3498db; border-radius: 50%; 
 
animation: spin 2.2s linear infinite; 
-webkit-animation: spin 2.2s linear infinite; 
-o-animation: spin 2.2s linear infinite; 
-ms-animation: spin 2.2s linear infinite; 
-moz-animation: spin 2.2s linear infinite; z-index: 52;}

#loader::after{content: ""; position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px; bottom: 20px; right: 20px; border: 3px solid transparent; border-top-color: #BC00C5; border-radius: 50%; 
 
animation: spin 2.2s linear infinite; 
-webkit-animation: spin 2.2s linear infinite; 
-o-animation: spin 2.2s linear infinite; 
-ms-animation: spin 2.2s linear infinite; 
-moz-animation: spin 2.2s linear infinite; z-index: 52;}

@keyframes spin {
0% {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); 
 -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
 transform: rotate(0deg);
} 
100% {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
 -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
 transform: rotate(360deg); 
}
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
0% {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); 
 -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
 transform: rotate(0deg);
} 
100% {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
 -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
 transform: rotate(360deg); 
}
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
0% {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); 
 -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
 transform: rotate(0deg);
} 
100% {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
 -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
 transform: rotate(360deg); 
}
}

#loader_wrapper .loader-section {position: fixed; top: 0; width: 51%; height: 100%; background-color: #2E0143; z-index: 51;}
#loader_wrapper .loader-section.section-left {left: 0;}
#loader_wrapper .loader-section.section-right {right: 0;}

/* Load finished -START- */

.loaded #loader_wrapper .loader-section.section-left {
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
 -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
 -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
 -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
 transform: translateX(-100%);
 -webkit-transition: all 1.9s 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000);
    -o-transition: all 1.9s 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000);
    -ms-transition: all 1.9s 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000);
    -moz-transition: all 1.9s 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000);
    transition: all 1.9s 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000); 
}

.loaded #loader_wrapper .loader-section.section-right {
 -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
 -o-transform: translateX(100%);
 -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
 -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
 transform: translateX(100%);
 -webkit-transition: all 1.9s 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000);
    -o-transition: all 1.9s 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000);
    -ms-transition: all 1.9s 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000);
    -moz-transition: all 1.9s 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000);
    transition: all 1.9s 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000);
}

.loaded #loader {opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.4s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
    transition: all 1.2s ease-out; 
}

.loaded #loader_wrapper {visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
 -o-transform: translateY(-100%);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
 -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
 transform: translateY(-100%);
    -webkit-transition: all 1.9s 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 1.9s 1s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1.9s 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1.9s 1s ease-out;
    transition: all 1.9s 1s ease-out; 
}
/* Load finished -END- */
/* Spinner -END-*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="loader_wrapper">
  <div id="loader"></div>
  <div class="loader-section section-left"></div>
  <div class="loader-section section-right"></div> 
</div>

<h1>Hi, gangsta!</h1>
```

А вот с твоим сниппетом:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#preloader_wrapper").fadeOut(3000);
});
```

```css
body {
  background:white
}

#preloader_wrapper {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 20;
 background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.preloader {
position:absolute;
  z-index: 21;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
    /* change size for your project */
}
.preloader hr {
  border:0;
  margin:0;
  width:40%;
  height:40%;
  position:absolute;
  animation:spin 3s ease infinite}

.preloader :first-child {
  background:black;
  animation-delay:-1.5s
}
.preloader :nth-child(2) {
  background:grey;
  animation-delay:-1s
}
.preloader :nth-child(3) {
  background:black;
  animation-delay:-0.5s
}

.preloader :last-child {
  background:grey;
}

@keyframes spin{
  0%,100%{transform:translate(0)}
  25%{transform:translate(160%)}
  50%{transform:translate(160%, 160%)}
  75%{transform:translate(0, 160%)}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="preloader_wrapper">
<div class="preloader">
  <hr><hr><hr><hr>
</div>
</div>

<h1>Hi, gangsta!</h1>
```